# What is easiest way to construct a bar graph with pattern in bars

Tags: ios, ipad, graph, core-graphics, core-plot

I am trying to implement a bar graph similar to the one shown below. I would like to what is the easiest way to implement this kind of pattern in bars. Only change is in the bar color. Patterns will be similar across each sections.

[image]

Could someone how to proceed with the implementation.

Comment: Did you look at `+ (UIColor *)colorWithPatternImage:(UIImage *)image` method of UIColor class?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure a pattern color (as suggested in the comments) would work. If it doesn't, you can use a tiled image fill.

Comment: I am trying to this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/33496/core-graphics-tutorial-patterns for implementing the pattern. But I am not sure how to pass a pattern color to 'CGPatternCallbacks' callback methods.

Could someone provide options.

Comment: @Eric, why do you think colorWithPatternImage will not work? If you can get an (e.g. 2x2 px) image of the pattern you want, you can set the background of your (bar) view to the color returned by colorWithPatternImage which basically will tile that image.

Comment: Core Plot converts images into Core Graphics images (`CGImageRef`) before drawing. I haven't tried using one, so I can't guarantee the pattern will survive the conversion.